# Как нажать на кнопку с помощью python + requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

делаю парсер с olx, там для просмотра номера телефона нужно нажать на кнопку.
пример https://www.olx.kz/obyavlenie/wi-fi-modem-2v1-dvuh-antennyy-300mbit-adsl-2-IDinAlO.html#f9f01ff837

как можно нажать на эту кнопку и спарсить номер телефона без использования selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Это нельзя сделать связкой python+requests

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо использовать Selenium + WebDriver. [Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/) можно прочитать больше.